# Animate fluid view based on gravity sensor values

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-sensors

**I want to rotate a view based on the gravity sensor values like this:**

[image: example gif]

***Gravity Sensor Listener in Java Activity file:***

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    ImageView fluid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fluid);
    fluid.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(acos(y / 9.8)));
    if (x < 0) {
        fluid.setRotation(fluid.getRotation() * -1);
    }
}
```

***XML activity file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.patmyron.blackbox.Puzzle1Activity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blink00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blink00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:background="@drawable/blink00"
        android:cropToPadding="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blink00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blink00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blink00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fluid"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:layout_width="1000000dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:layout_height="1000000dp"
        android:background="#99DE083B" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***It currently looks like:***

[image: view of activity gif]

Setting width and height to `1000000dp` does not work because the screen boundaries limit the size on initial startup but when tilted, you can see empty space because the rectangle is no longer big enough to cover the whole space...

Comment: I think you will need to build a custom view and handle the `onDraw()` yourself. It's not that hard, but will take some experimentation and learning to draw with `Canvas`. That way you can calculate how you want to fill the view, and draw that. If I would need to implement this, I would build a `View` that fills the whole screen, and then draws the red part according to needed rotation.

Comment: @Peterdk thank you for the advice. It did seem like I was going about this the wrong way.  I've never made a custom view before, so I will have to look into it.